# сделать стеклянную поверхность

Tags: c++, directx

У меня стоит задача - сделать из обычного квадрата, состоящего из двух треугольников - стекло, то есть, материал как бы должен быть не полностью прозрачным, а вот как в AeroGlass стиле для windows. Собственно волнует вопрос как реализовать. Первым делом мне пришло в голову поиграться с коэффициентом смешивания цветов приемника и источника, но там могут возникнуть куча вариантов, перебирать в ручную будет очень долго - может кто имел дело с подобным и знает какой коэффициент использовать, просьба подсказать пожалуйста. Ну а если есть другие способы реализации - пожалуйста подскажите.

Answer (score 2):

Стекло, это прозрачность около 98% (по Френелю уменьшается до 0%). Отражения по Френелю растут от 0 до 98% примерно. Спекуляр по вкусу и Цвет. Плюс Диффузия около 2-5%. В более сложном случае - преломление. А если все совсем серьезно, то еще и Каустика. Если стекло матовое, то Цвет и Диффузия побольше и Блюр того что за ним.

Стекло, больше чем другие материалы, завист от окружения, источников света, отражений. Если все это убрать, то от "стекла" ничего не останется.